# Should we migrate questions from Bitcoin SE and Stackoverflow to our site?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

There are

- 50 questions tagged `ethereum` on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ethereum).
- 43 questions tagged `ethereum` on [bitcoin stackexchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethereum).
- 13 questions tagged `smartcontracts` on [bitcoin stackexchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartcontracts).
- 3 questions tagged `solidity` on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solidity).
- 2 questions tagged `smartcontracts` on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartcontracts).

Should we migrate these questions to our site?

Comment: I'm suggesting edits to the ethereum tag wikis on the first two sites which point to this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless those questions are deemed off topic on those other sites, we have no cause to remove content from another site and the reputation/ownership that goes with it.

Besides, the wholesale importing of content from elsewhere is not really a great way to build a new site. Questions imported from elsewhere would likely be orphaned if the author does not have an account here; the tags probably wouldn't match; the posting might be different, and anonymous content always has that odd, back-dated feel of long-forgotten questions that no one really cares about any longer. If someone were to post another answer to one of those old threads, or even ask for a bit of followup, no one would receive the notification as they do now.

Essentially, we would be loading this site up with a lot of questions asked and answered a long time ago… without imparting any of the benefits of reputation, ownership, or experience into the community that is supposed to take care of it.

That's why we don't do it.

Answer (score 7):

No, that's not a good idea.

There are some issues with that suggestion:

1. You can't "pull them in", they have to be pushed over by the other site.
2. Once they have been on the site for a while they get "too old to migrate".
3. It is deprecated to ask identical questions on several sites.
4. Many sites don't consider beta sites as valid targets for migration.

Therefore my suggestion would be that you reask questions about interesting topics you find on other sites by creating new questions with your own words on your own site instead.