# Why do some people asking about Ethereum in stackoverflow instead ES

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I've noticed that many questions were asked about Ethereum on the stackoverflow, check the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ethereum

I think we should flag such questions, to be migrated toward this forum instead. They will find more help in this dedicated forum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we migrate questions from Bitcoin SE and Stackoverflow to our site?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/should-we-migrate-questions-from-bitcoin-se-and-stackoverflow-to-our-site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wondering about this the other day, and had a quick look into it. I was wondering if we could do something clever, like use a [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/) script to automatically migrate questions across. (I'm sure similar ideas have come up on other SE boards in the past... )

However, there are a few side-effects to migration that would have an effect on the both the user who posted the question and anyone who had already answered it. We'd potentially be affecting the reputation scores of people on other boards.

For example, in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work/10250#10250) post on the main StackOverflow Meta board:

> - **Down votes are cleared** from the question upon its migration
> - If a user who has participated in the question does not have an account on the target site, their username is displayed as plain text
>     until they create an account
> - **Answers on the origin site are deleted immediately** upon question migration (This causes a reversal of all associated reputation on the
>     origin site.)
> - **The question is left as a stub**, or pathway to the new site, **for 30 days**, after which it is automatically deleted (Again, this causes a reversal of all associated reputation on the origin site.)

There are also other considerations (again from the linked post)

> - **Don't migrate crap!** Ever. If the question is likely to be closed or deleted on the destination site anyway, don't bother migrating it.
>     Just vote to close it normally and advise the OP of the other site in
>     the comments. If they decide to improve the question, then they can go
>     post it over there, or they can edit their question so it's on-topic
>     on the original site.
> - **Check for cross-posts.** It may be possible, that after hearing about the other site, that the OP may cross-post their question onto
>     the other site. Therefore, check the intended destination site for
>     potential cross-posts before voting to migrate. If it has been
>     cross-posted, vote to close it instead, as cross-posting is prohibited
>     even if the question is on-topic on both sites.
> - **Avoid migrating answered questions.** The point of migration is to send the question to a place where it is on-topic and *can* get
>     answered. If the OP already has an answer, then we've already defeated
>     the purpose of migration and the destination site won't have anything
>     to do with the question. Avoid migrating these questions unless they
>     are of extremely good quality and risk deletion on their current site.
> - **Don't migrate for the sake of migration.** We only migrate questions because they are *off-topic on the original site*. It is
>     perfectly possible for a question to be on-topic on multiple sites,
>     but that is not a reason to migrate it elsewhere, unless the OP
>     requests migration. As a general rule, if someone asks a question
>     *here*, and it's on-topic *here*, it should stay *here*.
> - **Be familiar with the destination site.** If you have never even visited the destination site before, read through its about page and
>     help center thoroughly and *make sure* the question actually belongs
>     there. Don't just look at the name of a site and automatically assume
>     that the question can be asked there. Each site has its own rules, and
>     rules vary greatly across sites.
> - **If you're not sure, don't vote to migrate it.** Let someone else who *is* sure do that, or ask for opinions from the community in a
>     relevant chat room.

I'm not saying we shouldn't be more proactive about migrating, it's just that it might be slightly more complex than first thought.